# PowerShell command not working

Tags: powershell

First question:

```
Get-Mailbox abc@win.com | FL IsLinked
```

it gives me the result `False`, which is true because my mailbox is not linked, but when I tried this:

```
[bool] Get-Mailbox abc@win.com | FL IsLinked
```

it returns `True`. I can't understand why this happens.

Second question is related to SSL certificate validation:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\localMachine\My | Test-Certificate -Policy SSL
```

which reports that `Test-Certificate` is not recognized as a cmdlet, or script or operable program.

Third one is related to `Get-WebconfigurationPropery` command: I am trying to get authentication mode of website hosted in IIS.

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter //authentication/files -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site'
```

It returns nothing.

Comment: Please do not mix questions. If you have three different questions: post three different questions. And you may want to clarify the first one, as it's not clear what your expected and actual results really are. Also, what Windows version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Casting to bool**

The problem is that you are casting the result of `Format-List IsLinked` to `bool`, not the value of the `IsLinked` property. When casting to `bool` then nothing, 0 or false returns `$false`, while anything else returns true. `Format-List` ouputs `IsLinked: false` which is "any output" and because of that the cast to `bool` returns `$true`.

Example:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{ IsLinked = $false }

#Show the objects in a list, but only the IsLinked-property
$obj | Format-List IsLinked
IsLinked : False

#Cast output from format-list .. to bool..
[bool]$obj | Format-List IsLinked
True
```

What you want is to just read the property using one of the solutions below

```
(Get-Mailbox abc@win.com).IsLinked
Get-Mailbox abc@win.com | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IsLinked
Get-Mailbox abc@win.com | Foreach-Object { $_.IsLinked }
```

**Test-Certificate**

This cmdlet was introduced in PowerShell 4.0 in Windows 8. You need to use Windows 8 or later as it is not included in PowerShell 4.0+ for Windows 7 AFAIK.

**IIS authentication mode**

See example on [Get-WebConfiguration @ TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790561.aspx)

> EXAMPLE 1: Querying authentication settings
>
> ```
> IIS:\>Get-WebConfiguration system.webServer/security/authentication/* 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site' -Recurse |
> where {$_.enabled -eq 'true'} |
> format-list
> ```
>
> This example queries for all authentication settings specified under
>   the Default Web Site.

Comment: Thanks for replay.but for iis authentication given cmdlet doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

Dot the property:
 `[bool] (Get-Mailbox abc@win.com).IsLinked`

Second question: Works fine for me.

Overall, would be better, to create/check questions seperately. Also give some Information about the Scenario.

Comment: is there any module to import before executing test-certificate command??

Comment: It belongs to the PKI module and should be available in 2008 R2 and newer.